# Two "Windows 7 loaders" in Grub2 screen

Tags: grub2, windows

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the same hard drive(sda) which already has Windows 7 OS installed on another partition of this hard drive and I also have a second hard drive(sdb) which is just for backup purpose(no OS installed). Now the problem is, when the computer boots up to the Grub2 window... it shows Ubuntu and two Windows 7 loaders(sda1) and (sdb1).... I formatted (sdb) thrice using Windows 7 OS and Ubuntu OS and Gparted application.
How do I get rid of this second "Windows 7 loader(sdb1)" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when I see 2 Windows entries in GRUB it is because of the system partition Windows 7 installation creates apart from the actual partition (C: Drive) you would use. The system partition is normally around 100 MB. When GRUB reads that it sees that the filesystem is Windows 7. When it continues reading partitions it sees your C: which is also Windows 7, and so it shows both. There could be other cases that it could show 2 partitions, but this is the most common.

There are several ways to remove that entry, but the easiest way would be with **Grub Customizer**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open Dash and type `grub customizer`. From there you can simply delete the entry and save the changed.